# Update system uptime every second

Tags: java, android-studio

I have created a simple application to do exercises and rehearsals in general, I'm trying trying to update a variable every second but I can't find a working way.

The code is this:

```
long milliSec = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    String upTime = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
            "%02d giorni, %02d:%02d:%2d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(milliSec),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSec) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(milliSec)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSec) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSec)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSec) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSec)));
```

The upTime variable I am putting in an array of strings. Can anyone kindly help me overcome this little obstacle?
Thanks a lot to everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is your question.

- You have the system uptime rather than the current time
- You want to update a variable every second.
- You store the updated variable in an array of strings.

Which of the three do you want to change?

Format the current time into a readable string using [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Format the uptime using [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) and [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) like

```
Instant startTime = Instant.now(); // to this once on application start
Duration d = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()); // do this evey second
String s = String.format("%s days and %sh %sm %ss", duration.toDays(),
        duration.toHours() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(duration.toDays()),
        duration.toMinutes() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(duration.toHours()),
        duration.getSeconds() -  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(duration.toMinutes()));
```

Remaining is to execute the code every second. I recommend placing this code inside a Runnable:

```
Instant startTime = Instant.now();
while (true) {
    Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
    String s = String.format("%s days and %sh %sm %ss", duration.toDays(),
            duration.toHours() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(duration.toDays()),
            duration.toMinutes() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(duration.toHours()),
            duration.getSeconds() -  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(duration.toMinutes()));
    // place the string wherever you need it
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

then have it running in a background thread. It will not exactly go every second but the reported uptime will be dead right.

Comment: I was unclear in the text, the code I shared returns the system uptime since the last boot: `xx days hh: mm: ss`